# Unable to refer a project from another project in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a working C# application . Into this application i need to add support of the following project [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#about_article) called WPF Notification . I want to use its features .

Now i have already added this project to my solution . I am unable to refer it correctly in my project . So my solution file is this

```
Solution 
      Project 1 ( My Project )
      Project 2 ( WPF Project )
```

Trying to follow the instructions given in the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#about_article) @ Tutorial Part 1: The Basics i get an error saying that the

```
" The TaskbarIcon does not exist in the namespace "http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
```

XAML CODE :

```
<Window x:Class="bbb"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
   <Grid>
    ...
       <tb:TaskbarIcon
      IconSource="/Icons/Error.ico"
      ToolTipText="hello world" />
    </Grid>
```

Note : IconSource may throw an error but thats ok . Once TaskbarIcon is recognized it shall be fixed .

I am very new to C# so i am unsure how do i fix this . There may be a simple way to fix but i am unable to get it .

Comment: Right Click on Project 1 select add reference, it will bring up an Add Reference Dialog which has a Projects Tab select that and you should see your Project 2,  select it and Add. Everything should work after that.

Comment: @MarkHall that should be entered as an Answer.

Comment: @MarkHall I had done that before posting . This is the problem after having added the reference .

Comment: are you doing this in Xaml or your codebehind.

Comment: @rockstar can you post your XAML code?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are wanting to include the project instead of just consuming the Dll that it creates?

Comment: @MarkHall as i said i am new so i am unsure if i shld do that . if it solves the problem i am ok with it :-) Its just that i dont know how :(

Comment: @MarkHall i think you guys should help me in providing a general solution of adding a project recurciely to another project and how to refer it ( Thats why i added the image of the structure of my project ) . I am pretty sure its not a specific case of the library that i am using . Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably just complile your WpfTaskBar project and then go to your Toolbox, right Click on it and select Choose Items, then Browse to the Directory that has the Wpf-notifyicon source. you will then need to drill down to `wpf-notifyicon\NotifyIconWpf\bin\Release` and select the `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll` this will add the control to your Toolbox then you can drop it on your Window.  If that is not available you will probably need to compile the wpf-notifyicon project first to generate the dll. Which in retrospect might be the issue you are currently having.

Comment: Thank you . I was looking for this . +1 for your time & support .

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to the project (as specified by @Mark Hall in the comments) would do it